# Android: Two gestures are detected in one gesture

Tags: android

I am making an app that needs to detect clicks(I used `onSingleTapUp` for this)and holds(I used `onShowPress`). The problem is sometimes a click that I make is registered as a hold first, and then a click. Is there any way to work around this?

P.S I am not looking for a long click so I am not using `OnLongClickListener`

P.S.S I've tried using an `OnClickListener`for the click and a `SimpleOnGestureListener` for the hold but the gesture isn't detected

Relevant code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ground);
        gl = new GestureDetector(this,new MyGl());
}
 class MyGl extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("motion","single");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e){
            Log.i("motion","long");
        }
    }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return gl.onTouchEvent(e);

    }
```

I was hoping to see only "single" logged but "long" was logged first and then "single". Two gestures are detected within one.

Comment: Umm why the down vote? I tried looking for solutions online but couldn't

Comment: A click is basically a hold for a period of time that you're ON the device right? I think you need to explain a little deeper what you're trying to do from the perspective of the APIs you are using and what the problem is with respect to the MotionEvents. And explain why OnLongClickListener doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am looking for something like a quick tap and a hold. A longclicklistener doesn't work because the user has to release their finger after a period of time for it to work, but I don't want that. I tried to tap quickly on my app, but it was detected as a hold first, and then a tap, but I don't know why that is happening.

Comment: Can you post some code, that'll provide more context on what you've tried.

Comment: Ok I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

kind of sounds like the API is not intended to be used directly (without constraints) with onSingleTapUp vs onDown . You should consider reading the documentation @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDown(android.view.MotionEvent) it clearly says:

> This will be triggered immediately for every down event

You need to filter it out according to certain specifications. Reading the documentation will explain why.

Perhaps you should consider handling the TouchEvent yourself and filter the touch logic for what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "the api isnt intended to be used directly with onsingletapyp vs ondown". onDown should be returning true for everything else to work right?  Can you give an example please?